# Routes in ReactTS based chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-router, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm a bit confused regarding the process of creating routes using react-router, and it seems like there's barely any information regarding the react-router and chrome extension, and if you do end up reaching to something, then it's seriously out dated.

The confusion occurs due to the fact that when the extension loads (popup script loaded), it's detached from Browser, and it has no actual urls. It's all 'locally', in the installed up.

Assuming I have an index.tsx file which from there i'm starting my Authentication process, heading to different 'pages' (components loading within the extension), what would be the best practice for routing within my extension?

Comment: You need to use hash mode in your router, IIRC. Note that the popup is indeed a separate page with its own chrome-extension:// URL, which is why standard routing for web pages doesn't work (extension pages don't have a server, they're like file:// pages but privileged).

Comment: Did you figure anything out? I am also hunting for an answer.

Comment: Yes. Will write a proper answer to it now so it can help out.

Answer (score 1):

As a chrome extension is running locally (you're creating a build -- the build folder is then being loaded via Extensions option in your browser), then the common routing is not really useful, as there is no actual communication with a server, or a real end-point to reach to..
that's why I used [HashRouter by ReactRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router).

The usage is super simple, here's an example of usage:

1.import the two following components

```
import { RouterProvider, createHashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

2.In case you want the routings exist everywhere in your app, thenin your index file, where you are using 'ReactDOM.createRoot', create a 'createHashRouter object which's defining your possible routes, and what they're supposed to launch in that particular route:

```
const router = createHashRouter([{
  path: "/",
  element: <UserAuth />,
},
{
  path: "/login",
  element: <LoginPage />
},
{
  path: "/settings",
  element: <Settings />
},
{
  path: "/app",
  element: <App />
}])
```

3.Provide the routing option to all of your app by using RouterProvider and providing it the created routings object:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Good luck!